# Jasmine resolver promise

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I try to resolve a promise that logs message on a screen and increments a counter:

```
it("should log promise", (done) => {
    let counter = 0;
    Promise.resolve(() => {
        console.log("Promise Resolved");
        counter++;
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Counter = " + counter);
        done();
    }, 1000);
})
```

I set a timeout for a 1 second just be sure that promise is resolved. But the only log I get is:

```
LOG: 'Counter = 0'
```

This means that jasmine didn't register that console.log and a counter increment inside a promise. How to force jasmine to register events in a promise?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Jasmine. Carefully observe your console output and test the code in a console or in a NodeJS repl. You're using `Promise.resolve()` the wrong way. Probably I should say. [Go back to start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

Comment: I guess, the timeout uses the counter value = 0 and not the reference. Because the Promise is executed asynchronously, the 'old' value 0 is used.